# code to trigger powershell script file in azure vm in c# .net6 web api backend

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I want a c# .net6 web API code so that I could trigger the PowerShell script which is in azure vm in the backend c# web api .net6 , i tried to look web results but couldn't find any which suits my requirement

I tried to find the code to trigger PowerShell script in vm in the backend .net web API but only got the code for triggering local PowerShell script in backend c# .net

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "System.Management.Automation" namespace. Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates how to do this:

```cs
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Security;

// Define the VM credentials
string vmUserName = "vmusername";
string vmPassword = "vmpassword";
SecureString vmSecurePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in vmPassword)
{
    vmSecurePassword.AppendChar(c);
}
PSCredential vmCredential = new PSCredential(vmUserName, vmSecurePassword);

// Define the VM connection
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://vm-ip-address:5985/wsman"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", vmCredential);

// Create the PowerShell session
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
{
    runspace.Open();

    // Create a PowerShell instance within the session
    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        // Add the script to the PowerShell instance
        ps.AddScript("Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& 'C:\\path\\to\\script.ps1'}");

        // Invoke the script and get the output
        var output = ps.Invoke();

        // Do something with the output
    }

    runspace.Close();
}
```